# MS Word: Remove all continuous section breaks but keep next-page section breaks

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

I have a 600-page Word file that was originally written in WordPerfect (which I don’t have) and then exported to a .doc file by the author (who’s not technical at all).

Presumably because of this export, the file has about three or four continuous section breaks per page, meaning several thousand section breaks in all. These are annoying and useless, and I’d like to get rid of them.

The problem is that there are also about 50 or so next-page section breaks which should *not* be removed – they are the only visual clue I have that one chapter ends and another begins, since the author hasn’t used any kind of styling to separate headings.

Using Find and Replace, there is, as far as I can tell, only one character code that catches all section breaks, namely `^b`, with no way to distinguish between different types of section breaks.

So is there a way to target and remove *only* continuous section breaks while keeping next-page section breaks throughout the document?

Comment: Converted documents are a PITA to edit! I will see if I can come up with a macro. My guess is that the continuous breaks are margin changes that in Word should be indent changes. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/basic_formatting.htm#Margins_and_Indents. Look, though, for column number changes. You may want to retain those. Work with a copy.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon They are indeed a PITA! Don’t spend too much time on this, though – for the present document, I ended up just biting the bullet and going through it manually, setting proper styles on the chapter titles based on the next-page breaks and then just removing all the section breaks in one go. There are a lot of paragraphs that are first-line indented in the PDF I have of the WP file which aren’t indebted in Word – it’s quite possible that these are all the places where the continuous breaks went, but luckily I can easily fix that when I get things imported into InDesign.

Comment: *I decided it was too much for me before I read your response.* Easy way is to search for `^b` and manually decide at each one. Even for 600 pages and who knows how many breaks, for me, the macro would take longer if it is even possible. **For headers/footers, remember the StyleRef field.**